# How to vertically center div with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to vertically center a div (that is in another div) with flexbox.

I tried adding this, but doesn't work:

```
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
```

Here jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ms5s5uhy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the flex properties in the *parent* div:

```
#boss {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;           /* moved here from child div */
    align-items: center;     /* moved here from child div */
}

#kids {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ms5s5uhy/8/)

OR...

You could remove the `align-items` keyword property from the flex container and simply use `auto` margins on the flex item.

```
#boss {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;           
    /* align-items: center <-- REMOVE */
}

#kids {
    margin: auto;            /* adjusted */
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ms5s5uhy/17/)

Learn more here: [**Methods for Aligning Flex Items**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

Comment: Another really nice reference can be found here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/